# When to use io.BytesIO() in Python for modifying strings

Tags: python, string, io

I am studying the IO python module. 
I have the two following code snippets:

```
buffer = b""
buffer += b"Hello World"
buffer += b"Hello World"
buffer += b"Hello World"



import io 
with io.BytesIO() as f:
    f.write(b"Hello World")
    f.write(b"Hello World")
    f.write(b"Hello World")
```

To me these two block pretty much do the same thing.
The only difference is that the second works in place, while the first do not.

I have heard that the second way is usually faster, but I have no idea why.

Could somebody explain me when the second method is preferred in respect to the first (in string modifications)?

Answer (score 4):

[Bytes objects](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects) are immutable, so in-place addition creates a new object every time.  If the operation is repeated many times then this can cause poor performance. From the Python [sequence docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) (irrelevant parts omitted)

> 6. Concatenating immutable sequences always results in a new object. This means that building up a sequence by repeated concatenation will have a quadratic runtime cost in the total sequence length. To get a linear runtime cost, you must switch to one of the alternatives below:
>
> ...
>
> - if concatenating bytes objects, you can similarly use [bytes.join()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.join) or [io.BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/io.html#io.BytesIO), or you can do in-place concatenation with a [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray) object. bytearray objects are mutable and have an efficient overallocation mechanism
>
> ...